# Copy/Update Between Two Similar Lists

Tags: 2013

I have two lists:

- List A

  - Only **Managers** have access to this list
- List B

  - **Instructors** have View Only access to this list
  - This list has only one view filtered by [Me]

Each list has the same basic columns.

### Current Workflow:

- ItemCreated in List A --> Copy item to List B

### What I want to have:

- Item 10 in List A is edited
- Item 10 in List B is updated with revisions made in List A

What is the best method to accomplish this using only OOB functionality (No custom code and whatnot)?

#### What I have:

- SP 2013
- SP 2010 Workflows
- Site Owner Permissions

#### What I don't have:

- Server Access
- Permission to use custom code

Comment: Hi @Arden Shackelford welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement using SharePoint Designer workflow in a couple of steps.

1. Go to SharePoint Designer -> Open Site -> Go to Workflows from the left Menu.
2. From the ribbon select "List Workflows" -> select your "List A"
3. Make sure this workflow triggers on "an Item Updated".
4. Add an action "Update a ListItem"
5. Click "this list" to open a popup to select list and add fields.
6. In the Update List Item Popup, you have to find a List item using `Find the List Item` section. `Field` is select the field in List B to match. `Value` which matches the field value. e.g: as Below Screenshot

[image]

This does update **List B** when you update an item in **List A**.

Comment: Just to be clear, you can use the ID like this because List B is only added to when List A gets a new item, correct? So, this wouldn't work if List B was being added to manually as well (or from another workflow)?

Comment: The condition is just a sample you have to replace with your own condition. The field must be a unique field to return one list item (e.g: RegID). To say about that I took ID in my answer. It is not to copy and paste to your solution.

Comment: To be clear, I got this to work by adding a field in List B of "List A Item ID" and assigned the ID from List A to this field. Once I did this it worked like a charm.